# Installing Ghost CMS (self hosting on AWS EC2) seems to never complete

Tags: amazon-ec2, ghost-blog

I want to setup Ghost CMS on AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04, t2.micro instance) and followed through every instruction within their documentation: https://ghost.org/docs/install/ubuntu/

The issue, however, is when I applied the command: `ghost install`, it's just loading the 4/5 linking dependencies message for over 30 minutes. I deleted the instance and tried again several times but it is the same effect. Please view the below logs (as seen in terminal) for reference:

```
✔ Checking system Node.js version - found v18.17.1
✔ Checking current folder permissions
✔ Checking memory availability
✔ Checking free space
✔ Checking for latest Ghost version
✔ Setting up install directory
☴ Downloading and installing Ghost v5.62.0 > Installing dependencies > [4/5] Linking dependencies...
```

The installation doesn't seem to complete, does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Because it is a small instance, it may just take time. Another thing you can do is `ghost install -v` (or even `-vvv`) to see if you can get more detailed output to see what is actually going on or stalling. You can add that output to your question and it'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: Ok, will give it a try  @MagnieMozios

Comment: @MagnieMozios I tried ghost install -v and ghost install -vvv yet didn't see any detailed output, its the same as above (applied both commands separately since the same issue was coming up)

Comment: Oops, looks like it is `ghost install --verbose` or `ghost install -V` (https://ghost.org/docs/ghost-cli/#useful-options) to get detailed output. My bad.

Comment: @MagnieMozios it seems to stop at this line (been at this statement for around 5 minutes now):

verbose 280.239460162 Creating directory "/var/www/gapp/versions/5.62.0/node_modules/remark-parse/lib/util".

Comment: Hmm, doing some research it probably is the instance size. According to this post you need a minimum of 2GB RAM: https://forum.ghost.org/t/last-step-of-ghost-install-freezes/38686

Comment: Thanks for your help @MagnieMozios. I was able to find a solution via your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to @Magnie Mozios's insight, I was able to find a solution. GHOST CMS requires more than 2GB memory so needed to upgrade the instance type and avoid using `ghost install --verbose` command since it can lead to max buffer timeout. Just use `ghost install` instead.